# Is it possible see inside the function of matlab libary?

Tags: matlab, function

**ones* at matlab
will create vector of ones
but how ? 
where i can find ones.m ?
how can I see inside function ?
there is anywhere or anyway too see it ?*

Comment: `ones` is a built-in function of Matlab. There's a `ones.m` file but it only provides documentation, not code. `ones` is not implemented in Matlab code. It is written in C/C++, and the code is not publicly available. There are many other functions in Matlab that are not built-in and you can see their Matlab code by right-clicking the function name and selecting `Open [function name]`

Comment: To add on @Aziz comment, selecting `Open [function name]` works in the editor. In the command window, you can type `edit [function name]`.